# Prime checking algorithm

Tags: algorithms

What should the algorithm for checking prime numbers be? I have one:

1. Read a number
2. Initialize division
3. Check for divisibility by 2 and 3
4. If true, declare prime, otherwise not a prime

Please tell me if it's right. I see many algorithms here so I thought this might be okay. I haven't yet signed to CS Stack Exchange, and the level of the questions asked there is too high for grade 11.

Comment: This is an entire branch of mathematics and can't really be answered here, but what you are describing is a simple primality test. Unfortunately, the method of just testing factors is very slow for big numbers. Check out http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimalityTest.html

Comment: What is the concise question?

Comment: You're just checking divisibility by $2$ and by $3$?  $25$ is not a prime...

Comment: Check number of factors of the given number in a loop, something like: if(n%i==0) count++; If (count ==2) prime; else $\cdots$

Comment: Also have a look at the Wikipedia article on [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) for a sense of how sophisticated such algorithms have become (history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is not quite right. It appears you're partially implementing [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division), but missing a few steps.

To complete the process, you'd do this:

1. Get a number $n$
2. For each number $i$ from 2 to $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$

   - Check whether $i$ | $n$. That is, determine whether the remainder from $\frac{n}{i}$ is 0.
   - If any remainder is 0, that number divides $n$, so declare that $n$ is not prime and halt the process.
3. If none of the $i$ divide $n$, $n$ is prime.

You're only checking for divisibility by 2 and 3, but you need to check for divisibility by *all* numbers from 2 to $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$. An example pointed out in the comments of where your algorithm fails is 25, which is divisible neither by 2 nor 3, but is not prime.

Comment: You only need to check for divisibility of $n$ by primes not exceeding $\sqrt n$ because if $n$ is composite then the smallest divisor,  greater than $1$, of $n$ will be a prime not greater than $\sqrt n.$ For an alternate approach, see the Sieve of Erastosthenes.